# android.os.ServiceManager cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, mobile, service, android-sdk-2.3

Recently i have downloaded the src code of the browser from source.android.com(projects / platform/packages/apps/Browser.git /). 
In that am getting the error "android.os.ServiceManager cannot be resolved", if i execute it on eclipse as the build version 2.3 - api level 9.

Am i missin g something?? plz help me on this asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot build source.android.com applications on their own. They can only be built as part of a firmware image. Please follow the [instructions](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) to build the entire firmware. While you can use [Eclipse](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) to edit the firmware source, you will still use `make` to build the firmware.

Comment: hi, i have one doubt. Then why its importing "import android.os.ServiceManager" which is not listed in the api - 9?

Comment: @yokks: Because the Browser is part of the firmware. The Browser is not an Android SDK application. The firmware can refer to internal classes; SDK applications cannot.